customized marker (pgfdeclareplotmark) with color as argumeent
I am trying to customize the shape+color of a marker for a scatter plot. Everythink works when I hard-code the color (e.g. red):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\newcommand{\myStyle}{%
% define marker shape here
    \tikzset{marker/.style={circle, inner sep=1.5pt, fill=red}}
}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymarker}{%
    \node[marker] {};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\myStyle

\begin{axis}[]

\addplot[only marks, mark=mymarker, smooth] coordinates {
    (3, 0.5)
    (4, 0.6)
    (5, 0.4)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

However, I am struggling to make the color individually for each plot. I can define
\newcommand{\myStyle}[1]{%
% define marker shape here
    \tikzset{marker/.style={circle, inner sep=1.5pt, fill=#1}}
}

but I think I have to specify the color inside the block
\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymarker}{%
        \node[marker] {};
    }

to change the color for each addplot command.
However, I am not sure how to pass the color as an argument to the command \pgfdeclareplotmark.

Edit 1

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} % Ensure compatibility with pgfplots

% Declare macro to create customized markers with a specific color
\newcommand{\declareCustomMarker}[2]{%
    \pgfdeclareplotmark{#1}{%
        \node[circle, inner sep=1.5pt, fill=#2] {};
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[]

% Declare markers with different colors
\declareCustomMarker{mymarker-blue}{blue}
\declareCustomMarker{mymarker-green}{green}

% Use the blue marker for this plot
\addplot[only marks, mark=mymarker-blue, smooth] coordinates {
    (3, 0.5)
    (4, 0.6)
    (5, 0.4)
};

% Use the green marker for this plot
\addplot[only marks, mark=mymarker-green, smooth] coordinates {
    (2, 0.7)
    (4, 0.8)
    (6, 0.9)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

like this ?

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
    marker color/.store in=\markercolor,
    marker color=red % default color
}

\newcommand{\myStyle}[1]{%
    \pgfkeys{/tikz/marker color=#1} % set the marker color
    % define marker shape here
    \tikzset{marker/.style={circle, inner sep=1.5pt, fill=\markercolor}}
}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{mymarker}{%
    \node[marker] {};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\myStyle{red} % <= marker color here

\begin{axis}[]

\addplot[only marks, mark=mymarker, smooth] coordinates {
    (3, 0.5)
    (4, 0.6)
    (5, 0.4)
};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Not really. Suppose you add another addplot[only marks, mark=mymarker] but the markers should be green. You could add \myStyle{green} before plotting, but this will set the color green globally for all commands involving mymarker, also for the plot before where the markers are supposed to be in red.

In other words, I want to specify the customized marker color individually for each addplot command.

@Simon I see, I edited my answer.

Nice solution. Can you think of an even more generic version where we do not have to create a marker for each color, i.e something like mymarker{blue} for plot 1 and mymarker{green} for plot 2?
